# docker-compose импорт csv через while

Tags: bash, docker, while

Есть файл users.csv с содержимым

```
user1,domain1,password1
user2,domain1,password2
```

Есть скрипт импорта в mailu контейнер

```
while IFS=',' read -r login domain password; do

  docker-compose exec -T admin flask mailu user $login $domain "$password"

done < "users.csv"
```

Скрипт обрабатывает только первую строку csv. Помогите понять почему

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в конец команды `docker-compose exec ... < /dev/null`. У меня подобное "проглатывание" команд было с ssh, который по-умолчанию считывал весь `stdin`, ничего не оставляя для последующих `read`. Перенаправление ввода из `/dev/null` помогло с `ssh`, может быть вам поможет с докером

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно сделать по другому:

```
awk -F, '{system("docker-compose exec -T admin flask mailu user "$1" "$2" "$3)}' users.csv
```

Comment: помогло, благодарю

Answer (score 0):

Создайте массив:

```
users=( $(cat users.csv) )
```

И цикл по массиву:

```
for user in "${users[@]}"; do
   docker-compose exec -T admin flask mailu user ${user//,/\ }
done
```

Однако пробелы в деталях юзера потребуют дополнительных ухищрений.